# Azure Resource Manager deploy ignores solution and project build configuration for projects referring other projects

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, msdeploy, webdeploy, azure-resource-manager

My solution looks like this:

- armdeploy.sln (has reference to ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2)
- ClassLibrary1 (has reference to ClassLibrary2)
- ClassLibrary2

When i deploy in Release, ClassLibrary looks for ClassLibrary2 /bin/debug folder when i have chosen Release configuration and gets an error because nothing is there.

The only way I can fix this is when i edit the csproj file in ClassLibrary2 and change the configuration condition to be set to Release when empty.
`<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>`

It's similar to this problem:
[VS2015 Azure Resource Manager deploy dialog ignores solution and project build configuration for referenced projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477068/vs2015-azure-resource-manager-deploy-dialog-ignores-solution-and-project-build-c)

But that seem to be fixed, in this case it's a problem when you have nested references.

Comment: Are you seeing this only when you have the nested reference?  Or all the time?  Also what version of VS and the Azure SDK do you have?  We had an issue with this that was fixed a while back but may not have fixed all scenarios...

Comment: It's only when I have nested reference. Version for VS is: 15.1 (26403.7) and Azure SDK is: 2.9

Comment: Got it - thx...